# ReportViewer: работа с картинками

Tags: c#

Мне надо в report вставить картинку, которая представлена в виде массива байт. Как мне можно это сделать?

Вот как я делал:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\111\Desktop\123.jpg";

string image = ImageToBase64(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path),System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp );

_reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("image", path)); 
_reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "..\\..\\Report4.rdlc";
                _reportViewer.RefreshReport();

public string ImageToBase64(System.Drawing.Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Convert Image to byte[]
        image.Save(ms, format);
        byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return base64String;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251715(v=vs.80).aspx) и [Вот](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsreportcontrols/thread/ccb3c0b3-343a-4a2e-a0af-70673af85049), вроде то что Вам нужно